# Form in modal is not writing new user data to Database

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4

I am trying to register new user in a modal, but I can not succeed.

In **home/index.html.twig** I am displaying modal by AJAX:

```
<div class="cell large-3 t-white bg-dark offset-2 pt-2">    
    <a onclick="createNew()"><img class="" src="{{ asset('images/add_button.svg') }}"></a>    //triggering ajax function
</div>

<div id="addUser" class="modal t-white">   //div for modal

function createNew() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "new",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#addUser').html(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    $('#addUser').css({display: 'block'});
}
```

**UserController.php**

```
/**
 * Creates a new User entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @Template()
 */

public function new(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $user->setPassword($encoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPassword()));

        $user->setRoles(["ROLE_USER"]);
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array('id' => $user->getId()));
    }
    return $this->render('user/new.html.twig',
        array('user' => $user,
              'form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```

**UserType.php**

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password');
    }
}
```

**user/new/html.twig**

```
<div class="modal t-white" id="addUser" style="display: block">
    <div class="box-container center-vertically t-white" id="addWindow">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="box-form">
                {{ form_start(form) }}

                {{ form_errors(form.username) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.username) }}

                {{ form_errors(form.password) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.password) }}

                <input class="button btn-custom-1" type="submit" value="Create"/>
                {{ form_end(form) }}
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#addWindow").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>
```

If I am trying to create new user not in /home route by modal, but in /new route (without modal), everything works fine and new user is recorded in database.

I would appreciate any help.
Thank You.

Comment: Forms will post to the current route by default, try setting the form `action` to `path('new')`.

Comment: Thanks for response. I  added action in UserController to $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user, ['action' => $this->generateUrl('new')]); And also in new.html.twig to  {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('new')}) }} But it didn't help.

Comment: You also have two `form` tags in your template, an html one and the one created by `form_start`. Use the network pane in your browser tools, is it posting to the correct route with the proper payload and are you getting any error? You could also use the WebProfiler to debug this.

Comment: I updated new.html.twig to   {{ form_start(form, {'action': path('new')}) }}

                
                {{ form_errors(form.username, {'action': path('new')}) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.username, {'action': path('new')}) }}

                {{ form_errors(form.password, {'action': path('new')}) }}
                {{ form_widget(form.password, {'action': path('new')}) }}

                <input class="button btn-custom-1" type="submit" value="Create"/>
                {{ form_end(form) }} but I see always I am redirected to home route. That is the problem.

Comment: You are doing a regular form submission without using ajax and your controller always redirects on success, so that's what I'd expect.

Comment: There are some errors in your code. You must call modal from the link where you actually call ``createNew()`` method. Furthermore, you must set ``data: {}`` values from form values, on ``createNew()``...

Comment: @Weenesta-MathieuDormeval Please, how should I call  modal from the link where I call *createNew()*? What data should I set to data: {} on createNew()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found very easy solution to my problem.
Just in **user/new.html.twig** change this line:

```
<form method="post">
```

to this:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('new') }}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the modal, you must replace this code on `home/index.html.twig`:

```
<a onclick="createNew()"><img class="" src="{{ asset('images/add_button.svg') }}"></a>
```

By this one :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUser">
  <img class="" src="{{ asset('images/add_button.svg') }}">
</button>
```

You must do an AJAX call on the form submit, like that :

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = "{{ path('new') }}";
    var serialized = $(this).serialize(); // Set ``data:{}``:
    $.post(url, serialized, function(response) {
        //your callback here
        console.log(response);
    }, 'JSON');
});
```

Best regards,

Comment: `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUser">
  <img class="" src="{{ asset('images/add_button.svg') }}">
</button>` is not calling modal.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap4, see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: To which file should I put that AJAX call?

Comment: On `home/index.html.twig` : `#form` is the id attribute of your HTML form view...